# Is there any way not to get a null return when query over a sort key in dynamodb using nodejs and serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I'm querying a dynamodb table with a partion key and a sort key using serverless framework and nodejs. I'm not sure to be using a correct syntax because if y add a condition over the sort key I'm always getting a null result.

I'm trying this:

```
//Table definition serverless.yml

resources:
  Resources:
    ConsentDynamoDBTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: domain
            AttributeType: S
          -
            AttributeName: ts
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: domain
            KeyType: HASH
          -
            AttributeName: ts
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 10
          WriteCapacityUnits: 10
        TableName: ${self:custom.tableName}


//THE QUERY

app.get("/consents/:domain/:startDate/:endDate", function (req, res) {

    const params = {
        TableName: DEV_TABLE,
        KeyConditionExpression: "#dom = :doma AND #tstamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#dom": "domain",
            "#tstamp": "ts"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":doma":        req.params.domain,
            ":startDate":   req.params.startDate,
            ":endDate":     req.params.endDate
        }
    };
        console.log("PARAMS: ", params);
    dynamoDb.query(params, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Could not get user" });
        }
        if (data.Items) { // HERE COMES THE ERROR --> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Items' of null
            res.json(data.Items);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
        }
    });
});
```

I should be seeing some output or even a [] (there are registers that match the query) but getting a null and:

```
console.log --> PARAMS:  { TableName: 'table-dev',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#dom = :doma AND #tstamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#dom': 'domain', '#tstamp': 'ts' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: 
   { ':doma': 'url.com',
     ':startDate': '1555857529129',
     ':endDate': '1555857536819' } }

2019-04-21 17:36:21.411 (+02:00)    c7f9720f-ea15-4e15-b508-9ffea47935dd    TypeError: Cannot read property 'Items' of null
    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:95:11)´´´
```

Comment: Log the output of `data` and see if there are any hints in there.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer, I had to parse the string to integer:

```html
const params = {
  TableName: DEV_TABLE,
  KeyConditionExpression: "#dom = :doma AND #tstamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
   "#dom": "domain",
   "#tstamp": "ts"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ":doma":   req.params.domain,
   ":startDate":  parseInt(req.params.startDate),
   ":endDate":  parseInt(req.params.endDate)
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such issues I like to use [dynamodb-sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@awspilot/dynamodb-sql) open source which enable working with Dynamo using SQL syntax

**Select Example**

```
/**
     *
     * @param dynamoConfig
     * @param sql
     * @param tableName
     * @param workFlowParams
     * @returns {Promise<*>}
     */
    static async getFromCache(dynamoConfig, sql, tableName, workFlowParams) {
        //Option 1 - Try to get results from Dynamo
        try {

            let db = require('@awspilot/dynamodb-sql')(dynamoConfig)
            return await db.queryp(`select * from ${tableName} where ${tableName}Key = '${SHA256(JSON.stringify(sql)).words.join('')}'`)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Failed to get from cache: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
            return [err, null]
        }

    }
```

**Insert Example**

```
static async updatePolicyLog (clientJobId, orgId, userId, policy, reason, dynamoConfig) {
        let db = require('@awspilot/dynamodb-sql')(dynamoConfig)

        let insert = `insert into ${tableId} set id = '${clientJobId ? clientJobId : shortId.generate()}',
                          orgId = ${orgId},
                          userId = ${userId},
                          createTime = '${moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS")}'`

        let [err, data] = await db.queryp(insert)
    }
```